# How to efficiently use IF + VLOOKUP and show the same VLOOKUP value if TRUE? (Libreoffice)

Tags: libreoffice, vlookup

I would like to use IF and VLOOKUP as a test criteria and in the THEN field I would like to set the same VLOOKUP result that I used in the Test field.

Example:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1;C1:E10;2;0)<>"something";VLOOKUP(A1;C1:E10;2;0);"NOT")
```

It works, but I want to change this formula above because it process two times the same VLOOKUP. I will use it in a sheet in 30 thousand cells. My solution is too slow. There is any one more efficient?

Sample data:
First Table have about 17000 rows

```
| CONFERENCE | JOURNAL |
| IEEE A4    |         |
|            | ACM19   |
```

And in second table i want to do:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A3:$A;Table1!$A$2:$L$500;4;0)="";VLOOKUP($A3:$A;Table1!$A$2:$L$500;5;0);VLOOKUP($A3:$A;Table1!$A$2:$L$500;4;0));""))
```

I want to put in the cells if the field conference is empty, the Journal column value, if not, the Conference column value, a thousand times.

Comment: Are you able to use a helper cell/column? You can run the `VLOOKUP` in it's own cell and then reference the result in your `IF`.

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't known if this is a good solution, because it will add more 30 thousand more cells with formulas to be calculated every time. But is more efficient than using double VLOOKUPS.

Comment: Perhaps if you give us sample data and explain what your are trying to do it would be easier to find a more efficient solution?

Comment: Sure, I will add some data editing the question.

Comment: Are there cases with both columns (Conference and Journal) are filled? What about both being empty?

Comment: No, no cases with both empty or both filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one value in columns `D` and `E`, then there is no need for an `IF` statement if you concatenate both `VLOOKUP` results:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Table1!$A$2:$L$500,4) & VLOOKUP(A2,Table1!$A$2:$L$500,5)
```

Since one `VLOOKUP` will always return an empty string, the result will automatically be the other string.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect solution!